# WPF can't find part of path in ShadowCache

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I have an image in a Asset class library project. The build action is Content and the Copy to Output Directory setting is Copy Always because I want to be able to allow users to replace these files without my intervention.

The problem is, I'm getting a design-time error (everything works find on compile and run) that says "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Designer\ShadowCache\oreaxsnr.cjd\orsr3pqd.wnf\Images\TestImage.jpg'."

I'm using `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);` to get the path of the assembly, and then I concatenate that with a `\\Images\\TestImage.jpg` string. Thinking that was the source of the problem, I commented out everything related to getting that image, cleaned the solution, and rebuilt. It still has a problem with finding part of the path.

I went to the orsr3pqd.wnf folder and there's the class library .dll that calls the image, and nothing else. I deleted all of the ShadowCache folder after closing Visual Studio, restarted VS2013, and it immediately put two folders in the ShadowCache folder.

Maybe it's thinking there's supposed to be a resource in the .dll, even though I'm setting the build action to Content? Any direction would be helpful.

Comment: I added the `Images\TestImage.jpg` folder and file to the orsr3pqd.wnf folder and it seems happy for now. I don't think that's the long-term solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference it straight from the XAML if it is in a project that is part of the application like this:

```
<Image Source="/AssemblyName;component/Images/TestImage.jpg" />
```

If that doesn't work, then this should:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="pack://application:,,,
            /AssemblyName;component/Images/TestImage.jpg"/>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

If neither of these work for you, then I'd also suggest setting your image file *Build Action* to *Resource*, rather than *Content*.

Comment: I've messed around with various ways to reference the file. Using `pack://application:,,,` is supposed to be used with Resources, I think. The relative path might be an option, if it messes up again I'll try it.

If I have to set the Build Action to Resource, I will, but I want to  have our designer swap files out without me adding them to the project.